# Discord.js V12 Client.emit and TypeError:

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried improving code that didn't work so I went back to the old code then got this error

```
at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at Object.run (/workspace/commands/verify.js:11:29)
at Client.<anonymous> (/workspace/index.js:112:21)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
```

index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const { token, default_prefix } = require('./config.json');
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');
const canvas = require('discord-canvas')

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

const config = require('./config.json');
client.config = config;

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("error", console.error);

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('I am ready');
    client.user.setActivity("Unfair Top", {
        type: 'WATCHING'
    })
})

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    c = client.channels.cache.get("943205142151434331")
    client.channels.cache.get("943204976761663629").send(`Welcome to Exodium ${member}, for support go to ${c}.`)

    const image = await new canvas.Welcome()
        .setUsername(member.user.username)
        .setDiscriminator(member.user.discriminator)
        .setMemberCount(member.guild.memberCount)
        .setGuildName(member.guild.name)
        .setAvatar(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png" }))
        .setColor("border", "#8015EA")
        .setColor("username-box", "#8015EA")
        .setColor("discriminator-box", "#8015EA")
        .setColor("message-box", "#8015EA")
        .setColor("title", "#8015EA")
        .setColor("avatar", "#8015EA")
        .setBackground("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/degree-equirectangular-projection-space-background-nebula-stars-environment-map-hdri-spherical-panorama-d-illustration-200369002.jpg")
        .toAttachment()

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(image.toBuffer(), "welcome.png");

    client.channels.cache.get("943204976761663629").send(attachment)
})

client.on("message", async message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    
    if (message.channel.id == 944770295590432860) {
        if (message.content != "-verify") {
            return message.delete()
        }
    }

    let prefix = default_prefix

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
            || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

        if (!command) return message.reply("Unknown Command!");

        if (command.args && !args.length) {
            let reply = `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
            return message.channel.send("Unknown Command!");
        }

        if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
            cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
        }

        const now = Date.now();
        const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
        const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

        if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
            const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

            if (now < expirationTime) {
                const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
                let timeout = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setDescription(`❌ Wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} to use ${command.name} again.`)
                    .setColor("RED")
                return message.reply(timeout);
            }
        }

        timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
        setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);


        try {
            command.run(client, message, args);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
});

//Express
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.body.id
    verify(id);
});

async function verify(i) {
    try {
        var g = await client.guilds.cache.get("943025185295044608");
        var mem = await g.members.cache.get(i)
        var r = await g.roles.cache.get("943202823217221652");
        
        mem.roles.add(r);

        let userverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`✅ ${mem.username} have been verified`)
            .setFooter(mem.username + " may now enter Unfair.top server!", message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        client.channels.cache.get("944841210462367794").send(userverembed)

        let verifyedembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(":white_check_mark: You have been verified")
            .setFooter(mem.username + " may now enter Unfair.top server!", message.author.displayAvatarURL())

        mem.send(verifyedembed)
    } catch (e) {
        client.channels.cache.get("944841210462367794").send(`${i} was not verified`)
    }
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3081;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

client.login(token);
```

Verify.js

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: "verify",
    description: "Verify yourself to enter the discord server",
    cooldown: "10",

    run(message, args) {
        let member = message.author

        if (message.channel.id != 944770295590432860) return;
        
        message.delete()

        let verifyembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Unfair Top Verification")
            .setDescription(`[Click here to begin](https://exodium.digital/verify/?id=${member.id})`)
            .setFooter("Verification started for " + message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())

        member.send(verifyembed)
    }
}
```

It's probably a small error but ive been trying to fix it for ages.
I've tried switching "message" to "messageCreate"

I was trying to convert to v13 but then got stuck so I went back to old v12 then started getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing your command in the `client.on('message')`, you are giving it three parameters: `command.run(client, message, args)`, while in your `verify.js` file, you are only accepting two parameters which are not in the correct order, so your `message` parameter in the `verify.js` file is actually the `client` while the `args` parameter is the `message`. To fix your error, all you have to do is change the order of the parameters in the `verify.js` file to:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: "verify",
    description: "Verify yourself to enter the discord server",
    cooldown: "10",

    run(client, message, args) {
        let member = message.author

        if (message.channel.id != '944770295590432860') return;
        
        message.delete()

        let verifyembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Unfair Top Verification")
            .setDescription(`[Click here to begin](https://exodium.digital/verify/?id=${member.id})`)
            .setFooter("Verification started for " + message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())

        member.send(verifyembed)
    }
}
```

(Note: When comparing the channel id of the message, you are comparing it with a number. In `discord.js`, the ids are stored as strings, so I have corrected that as well